# python and selenium web scraping multiple drop down (1 or 2 or 3 or 4 dropdown) text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to output text of drop down on ebay. I want to output the text and then the price of the item as different drop down options are selected (which is why i don't want to scrape a list of dropdown values all at once). I have a code which works only with 1 drop down box and price .

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

sel = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='msku-sel-1']"))

for index in range(1, len(sel.options)):
    # skipping index 0 because it is not valid option
    sel.select_by_index(index)
    print("{}: {}".format(sel.first_selected_option.text, browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='prcIsum']").text))
```

[https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/APPLE-iPHONE-5S-16GB-32GB-64GB-Unlocked-EE-O2-Voda-Smartphone-Mobile/323645059709?epid=168509016&hash=item4b5abfb27d%3Am%3AmPVOlUVEGK642jC7sPt_4Yg&LH_BIN=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlTPI.png)

OR 
[https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/UK-Women-Off-Shoulder-Floral-Bodycon-Backless-Ladies-Summer-Beach-Midi-Sun-Dress/254198776097?hash=item3b2f6d8121:m:m9B15WsfVx5zTh_73LlzBGA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2kjF.png)

I want the output to be e.g

Color: White, Size: S Price:£4.99

Comment: I can't imagine that scraping ebay isn't against their TOS. You might check and see if they have an API, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to generate all the possible permutations, select them in the page and get the price for each.

Here's what worked for the site with 2 dropdowns:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

import itertools
from pprint import pformat


def apply_values(dropdowns, values):
    """
    :param dropdowns: list of select DropDown
    :param values: list of values to set
    :return: dict with key=dropdownName, value=dropDownValue
    """
    r = {}
    for value in values:
        # For each value, get the associated DropDown and set it
        for dropdown in dropdowns:
            if value in dropdown.values:
                try:
                    dropdown.select_by_visible_text(value)
                    r[dropdown.name] = value
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    # print("Unable to set the following values {}..Skipping".format(values))
                    # This is caused by an option not being available with other selected dropdown values
                    # You can also check the attribute disabled for this
                    return False
                break
    return r


driver = Chrome()
driver.get('yourUrl')
els = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".msku-sel")
selects = []
for el in els:
    # Adding the dropdown name to the select object
    name = el.get_attribute('name')
    select = Select(el)
    select.name = name
    selects.append(select)

print("Get all options for each dropdown")
for idx, sel in enumerate(selects):
    sel.values = [option.text for option in sel.options][1:]

print("Get all possible permutations")
permutations = list(itertools.product(*[sel.values for sel in selects]))

# Iteration for all possible permutation
print("Select all possible permutation and get price for each")
results = []
for permutation in permutations:
    # Resetting all parameter to default
    for sel in selects:
        sel.select_by_index(0)
    # Iteration to set each dropdown
    result = apply_values(selects, permutation)
    if result:
        # Once all dropdown value are set, get the finally price
        result['Price'] = driver.find_element_by_id("prcIsum").text
        results.append(result)


print(pformat(results))

driver.close()
```

Result:

```
Get all options for each dropdown
Get all possible permutations
Select all possible permutation and get price for each
[{'Colour': 'White', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '6'},
 {'Colour': 'White', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '8'},
 {'Colour': 'White', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '10'},
 {'Colour': 'White', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '12'},
 {'Colour': 'White', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '14'},
 {'Colour': 'White', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '16'},
 {'Colour': 'White', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': 'S'},
 {'Colour': 'White', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': 'M'},
 {'Colour': 'White', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': 'L'},
 {'Colour': 'White', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': 'XL'},
 {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '6'},
 {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '8'},
 {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '10'},
 {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '12'},
 {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '14'},
 {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '16'},
 {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': 'S'},
 {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': 'M'},
 {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': 'L'},
 {'Colour': 'Blue', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': 'XL'},
 {'Colour': 'Light Green', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '6'},
 {'Colour': 'Light Green', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '8'},
 {'Colour': 'Light Green', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '10'},
 {'Colour': 'Light Green', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '12'},
 {'Colour': 'Light Green', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '14'},
 {'Colour': 'Light Green', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': '16'},
 {'Colour': 'Light Green', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': 'S'},
 {'Colour': 'Light Green', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': 'M'},
 {'Colour': 'Light Green', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': 'L'},
 {'Colour': 'Light Green', 'Price': '£6.99', 'Size': 'XL'}]
```

I have used pformat to print the result dict, but you can easily re-format for your desired expected output.

I have commented inside the code, but if you need clarification you can ask

Comment: this only works with that specific link  - e.g https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Womens-Ladies-Strappy-Maxi-Boho-Baggy-Dress-Holiday-Summer-Beach-Loose-Sundress/264160712785 throws the error   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 140, in select_by_visible_text
    raise NoSuchElementException("Could not locate element with visible text: %s" % text)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with visible text: Orange 2

Comment: this relies on the option being called the name hardcoded in the code. But option names can change. How can we edit this code to select by element id?

Comment: There is no name hardcoded in the code. We are getting the value set inside the html. I have edited the code. Issue is that when dropdown 1 as a value of X, it my not allows all the value in dropdown 2. Causing the exception. If it works, please don't forget to accept the answer.